# Undefined module error during runtime when everything is fine during compile on a Svelte app

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, svelte, electron-forge

I have started working on an Electron-Forge/Svelte based application and I'm running into some issues early on with my setup properly referencing modules/stores during runtime.

Specifically this error: `svelte.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: auth is not defined at svelte.js:9`

Which is pointing to this line:

```
const app = new App({
    target: document.body
});
```

Now, under the `src` directory I have the following subdirectories: `['src/stores', 'src/models', 'src/api', 'src/routes', 'src/services']`

I use these to help break up where I put various things such as interfaces, stores, logic for external services and so on.

I am using VSCode, and at least during development I have no errors that indicate there are any issues resolving modules. That said, I'm not a front end guy, and there are things about the setup which I'm not happy with at the moment...the most important being it doesn't actually work.

So here is my `tsconfig.js`:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Here is my `eslintrc.json`:

```
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One reason I know things aren't great just from a VSCode perspective is that I'm having to reference the modules from each other like this:

From `routes/Home.svelte`: `import { authStore } from "stores/auth";`

From `api/service.ts`: `import { PlayerInterface } from "../models/player";`

From `stores/auth.ts`: `import { submitEmailForAuth, syncPlayer } from "../api/server"; import PlayerState from '../models/player'`

I don't like the inconsistency with how they are referenced, but this is the way VSCode doesn't complain and I can at least build even if I get a runtime error. If I attempt to change the imports in the modules, other than `Home.svelte`, to be relative references I can't even compile because I get errors about finding those modules.

I have run out of ideas for why the code can't find `auth` on startup, and there is absolutely no stack trace for me to even begin to try to figure out what's wrong.